# Questions about the Queue insertion and deletion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, queue

I'm not sure what "rear = -1" is in the queue algorithm of the image. And if you proceed with the insertion in the form of a queue as shown in the picture, does the 'front' move and point to the next index?
[image]

I've been searching Google for similar cue forms or problems for a long time, but I couldn't find them

Comment: Where did you get this from? It makes no sense. If n is 5 like in the image, then calling enQueue and deQueue in sequence, and repeating this 5 times, will make both `rear` and `front` equal to -1, and so both `isFull` and `isEmpty` will return true. This is crap.

Answer (score 0):

According to me rear moves by -1 when you add one item in the queue and when t you insert at the start of queue i.e 0th index then it is decremented by -1 specifying that it is full now . When you dequeue, front starts from the last index as queue is FIFO algorithm so front moves and points to the next index.